# Which Anaconda Installer to choose for my Linux system?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, data-science

I want to install Anaconda on my machine with the following features:

- OS:  Ubuntu 20.04.2
- CPU: Intel i7-8550U (8) @ 4.000GHz

But the installers on the Anaconda website are the followings:

- 64-Bit (x86) Installer (544 MB)
- 64-Bit (Power8 and Power9) Installer (285 MB)
- 64-Bit (AWS Graviton2 / ARM64) Installer (413 M)
- 64-bit (Linux on IBM Z & LinuxONE) Installer (292 M)

And no one seems to match my machine.

Which one should I choose?

Comment: you have a "64-bit (x86)" machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sure, [check this installation guide.](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-20-04/) it might be helpful